# how to return a child method from its parent method?

Tags: java, oop

```
Class parent {

protected void myMethod() {
 if(someCodition) {
 //return this as well as child's myMethod.
  }
}

Class child extends Parent {

@override
protected void myMethod() {
super.myMethod();
 //code below this line should not execute if someCondition.
 //want parent to handle all this
  }
}
```

Please don't suggest to take some boolean flag kind of thing in parent class and check it in child. actually child class will be used by other developers and i dont want them to take care about any such condition, so want to exit from parent itself.

I am fully aware that it is violation of Abstraction principle of oops, but its my need to violate .

**Updating**

PS: to call myMethod() is not in either child or parent's control , so can not create a separate method as mentioned in one answer .
actually its and API method, so system will execute it automatically as per need, and i can not stop to call it.

Comment: A simplified concrete example--and syntactically correct code--would increase your odds of getting a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) [or some variation of it]

The user will override the protected method `myTemplateMethod()`, and  `myMethod()` will not be overriden.

`myMethod()` will invoke `super.myMethod()` [it was not overriden so actually the super will be invoked immidiately], and the super will invoke [if conditions are met] `myTemplateMethod()`

Something along the lines of [pseudo code]:

```
abstract Class parent {

protected abstract void myTemplateMethod();

protected final void myMethod() {
 if(someCodition) {
    myTemplateMethod();
  }
}

Class child extends Parent {

@override
protected void myTemplateMethod() {
 //code that will be invoked only if someCodition is met
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.given me idea that possible solution might be create a different method which will call from parent only . love to upvote it , but can not accept as answer. want to know why ?? please  see updated question .

Comment: @ShailendraRajawat: I read the edit, the API method remains `myMethod()`, the overriden `myTemplateMethod()` will be invoked only from the super's `myMethod()`. The API does not change at all due to the template method pattern usage, the only thing that does change is that the subclasses will override `myTemplateMethod()` instead of `myMethod()`. Invokation remains to be by using `myMethod()`.

Comment: Agree.seems my dream to provide same name myMethod() can not come true . thanks for your effort. going with this solution.